# Clickable url value in ag-grid with react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm currently giving [`ag-grid`](https://www.ag-grid.com/) a try and trying to build a table where if the user clicks a column value, they are taken to a page containing that entry's details.

**How can I make a cell value clickable in ag-grid?**

I've tried using `valueGetter: this.urlValueGetter` with `columnDefs` and:

```
urlValueGetter(params) {
  return '<a href=\'bill/' + params.data.id + '\'>details</a>';
}
```

but it now looks like this:

[image]

I then tried using `template: '<a href=\'bill/{id}\'>details</a>'` which does show the cell text as clickable but the id is not replaced. I assume this could work if I could somehow pass in the id?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use a `cellRenderer` for that, instead of `valueGetter`:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#gsc.tab=0

Random example from above documentation:

```
// put the value in bold
colDef.cellRenderer = function(params) {
    return '<b>' + params.value.toUpperCase() + '</b>';
}
```

You can return a string (easier) with your link if you don't want to attach any events.

Otherwise, here's an example of a `colDef` if you want to attach events to an element:

```
{
    headerName: 'ID',
    field: 'id',
    cellRenderer: (params) => {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '#';
        link.innerText = params.value;
        link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(params.data.id);
        });
        return link;
    }
}
```

Comment: As above, but the cell renderer can also be a React component by using cellRendererFramework

Comment: Try to only use the React component version if you *really* need to, it can be slower than the native DOM version. It matters more with lots of columns, or on slower computers, or if you're trying to keep the grid scrolling fast.

Comment: Yep, agreed - just thought it worth mentioning

Comment: Is there any way to do it for `react-router-dom 's <Link>`?

Comment: @Sushmit: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory programmatically navigate with `.push()`.

Comment: Finally I realized that my code had JSX rather than plaintext for the HTML, so that's why my ag-Grid cellRenderer wasn't working. Thanks. Also helpful: https://blog.ag-grid.com/adding-hyperlinks-to-the-grid/

Answer (score 3):

Since you've already used React, you should use `frameworkComponent` instead. Somebody mentioned about the overhead of React but because this is a very simple component, I do not think it matters much in this case.

Anyway, here is the example setup.

```
function LinkComponent(props: ICellRendererParams) {
  return (
    <a href={"https://yourwebsite/entity/detail?id=" + props.value}>
      {props.value}
    </a>
  );
}

...

// in your render method
<AgGridReact
  {...}
  columnDefs={[...,{
    headerName: "Detail",
    field: "detail",
    cellRenderer: "LinkComponent"
  }]}
  frameworkComponents={{
    LinkComponent
  }}
/>
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit demo app on CodeSandbox]

Answer (score 0):

Try this for newer versions:

```
cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> {params.value} </a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).