# Ag-Grid Link with link in the cell

Tags: ag-grid

I am building angular 4 app with ag-grid and I am having an issue with trying to figure out how to put a link in the cell. Can anybody help me with that issue?
Thanks

Comment: did you ever find the solution for this? Would you be willing to post? Looks like the only answer below is for javascript, looks like you need typescript solution..

Comment: This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218532/clickable-url-value-in-ag-grid-with-react#comment123766268_45231951

Answer (score 40):

Please check this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/anJSAE?p=preview)

```ts
cellRenderer: function(params) {
  return '<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">'+ params.value+'</a>'
}
```

In this demo, the cell value for the column 'city' is a hyperlink.

Comment: You mean for the cell `Country` is a hyperlink.

Comment: angular 4 uses typescript, the solution you provide above is for javascript.

Comment: I really don’t understand why people downvote for no reason ! My answer is from my experience with ag- grid, don’t know why it needed to be downvoted!

Comment: This is a good answer, perfectly valid for Angular. If you inject Router into your component, it has functions on it that will allow you to construct the URL for a route link just like you would a routerLink attribute in a template, or sometimes the route link is easy enough just to build without any help as in shr's answer below. Something like building a reusable RouterLinkRendererComponent as also suggested below works too, but not necessary.

Answer (score 27):

I struggled with this the other day and it was bit more complex than I first thought. I ended up with creating a renderer component to which I send in the link and that needed a bit on NgZone magic to work all the way. You can use it in your column definition like this:

```ts
cellRendererFramework: RouterLinkRendererComponent,
cellRendererParams: {
    inRouterLink: '/yourlinkhere',
}
```

Component where inRouterLink is the link that you send in and params.value is the cell value. That means that you can route to your angular route that could look something like 'yourlink/:id'. You could also simplify this a bit if you don't want a more generic solution by not sending in the link and just hard coding the link in the template and not using the cellRendererParams.

```ts
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AgRendererComponent } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
    template: '<a [routerLink]="[params.inRouterLink,params.value]"  (click)="navigate(params.inRouterLink)">{{params.value}}</a>'
})
export class RouterLinkRendererComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
    params: any;

    constructor(
        private ngZone: NgZone,
        private router: Router) { }

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
    }

    refresh(params: any): boolean {
        return false;
    }

    // This was needed to make the link work correctly
    navigate(link) {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate([link, this.params.value]);
        });
    }
}
```

And register it in

```ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AgGridModule.withComponents([
            RouterLinkRendererComponent,
        ])
    ],
})
```

**UPDATE:** I have written a blog post about this: https://medium.com/ag-grid/enhance-your-angular-grid-reports-with-formatted-values-and-links-34fa57ca2952

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was having an issue when navigating that the target component was loading a blank template without making any calls to ngOnInit.

I had not realized that ag-grid executes CellRenderFrameworks outside the angular environment. NgZone to the rescue.

Comment: Important! Don't forget to add the component `RouterLinkRendererComponent` to a module as entryComponent. `entryComponents: [ RouterLinkRendererComponent ]`. Otherwise, you will recieve lots of ag-grid render errors.

Comment: Great solution. I have an improved version, for those who think you need a bit more flexibility, take a look of my version https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207311/2736817

Answer (score 11):

This is a bit dated, but it may help someone. The solution with typescript on Angular 5 is similar to what C.O.G has suggested.
In the component's typescript file, the column definition can contain a custom cell rendering function.

```ts
 columnDefs  = [
    {headerName: 'Client', field: 'clientName' },
    {headerName: 'Invoice Number', field: 'invoiceNumber',
        cellRenderer: (invNum) => 
              `<a href="/invoice/${invNum.value}" >${invNum.value}</a>` },
];
```

The lambda function is called while rendering the cell. The 'value' of the parameter that gets passed is what you can use to generate custom rendering.

Comment: Using href seems to work fine, but the problem with this is that it reloads entire angular app.. (Atleast it does for me?) routerLink doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Marius, did you setup the route paths for the links used in href ? If routes are setup properly, it shouldn't reload the entire angular app.

Comment: `href` and `routerLink` are completely different stories... I would create a simple component to wrap with a routerLink angular in the template and then add this component to columnDefs as a column. It is almost identical what Michael suggested above.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @Michael Karén

This is a improved version that is more flexible.

- We can set what text to display in link
- We can pass more than 2 routerLink parameters
- Resolve routerLink according to data
- Support target
- Display text only if link is not applicable
- And more if you wanted to add, just further edit this component

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';

export interface IRouterLinkRendererComponentOptions {
    routerLinkParams?: any[];
    linkDescription?: string;
    textOnly?: string;
    target?: string;
}

@Component({
    template: `
        <a *ngIf="params.textOnly == null; else textOnlyBlock" 
           [routerLink]="params.routerLinkParams" 
           [target]="params.target ? params.target : '_self'"
        >
            {{ params.linkDescription }}
        </a>
        
        <ng-template #textOnlyBlock>
            {{ params.textOnly }}
        </ng-template>
    `
})
export class RouterLinkRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    params: IRouterLinkRendererComponentOptions;

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params.routerLinkRendererComponentOptions(params);
    }

    refresh(params: any): boolean {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So that we can dynamically resolve parameters and return text only if wanted in column definition by

```ts
{
...
    cellRendererFramework: RouterLinkRendererComponent,
    cellRendererParams: {
        routerLinkRendererComponentOptions: (param): IRouterLinkRendererComponentOptions => {
            if (param.data.dispatch_adjustment) {
                return {
                    routerLinkParams: ['/adjustments', param.data.dispatch_adjustment.id, 'edit'],
                    linkDescription: '#' + param.data.dispatch_adjustment.id
                };
            } else {
                return {
                    textOnly: '-'
                };
            }
        }
    },
...
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using href in cellRenderer , it's better to use cellrenderer framework as route link works in it.
Another Disadvantage is if you use href then the entire angular application will reload again it changes the navigation state from imperative to popstate. The angular router works on the imperative state.

Answer (score 2):

I had implemented something similar to Michael and Tom, with only `[routerLink]` and no `(click)` handler. But recently I started getting the dreaded warning:

```
Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?
```

After experimenting for awhile I found this post and added the navigate click handler function, which made the application start working again, however I found that the '*Navigation triggered outside Angular zone*' message was still appearing in the logs.

So while the `(click)="navigate()"` call triggers the navigation inside the `ngZone`,the `[routerLink]` call is still being made, which bothered me. I really didn't want two attempts to navigate to happen - in case anything changed with a future API update.

I decided to replace the anchor tag with a span `pseudoLink`.

```css
.pseudoLink {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
@Component({
   template: '<span class="pseudoLink" (click)="navigate()">{{mytitle}}</span>'
})

navigate() {
  this.ngZone.run(
    () => {
      console.log("LinkRendererComponent: navigate: (", this.mylink, ")");
      this.router.navigate([this.mylink]);
    }
  );
}
```

`this.mylink` is defined in the `agInit()` method based on parameters passed in via `cellRendererParams`.

This works well for my main purpose which is to make the cell look like a link. Only thing I lost was the URL path popup in the browser status bar.

Hope this might help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I created a generic component that is usable for any link cell, uses no workarounds, and logs no warnings.

Usage

```ts
columnDefs = [
  {
    colId: 'My Column',
    cellRendererFramework: AgGridLinkCellComponent,
    cellRendererParams: {
      // `text` and `link` both accept either an string expression (same as `field`) or a function that gets ICellRendererParams
      text: 'title',
      link: (params: ICellRendererParams) => `/my-path/${_.get(params, 'data.id')}`
    }
  }
]
```

Register the component in your `AppModule`:

```ts
imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents([
      AgGridLinkCellComponent
    ])
]
```

The component itself:

```ts
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AgRendererComponent} from 'ag-grid-angular';
import {ICellRendererParams} from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ag-grid-link-cell-component',
  template: '<a [routerLink]="link">{{ text }}</a>',
})
export class AgGridLinkCellComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
  link: string;
  text: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.refresh(params);
  }

  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    const dataParams = params.colDef.cellRendererParams;
    this.link = _.isFunction(dataParams.link) ? dataParams.link(params) : _.get(params.data, dataParams.link);
    this.text = _.isFunction(dataParams.text) ? dataParams.link(params) : _.get(params.data, dataParams.text);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a cell renderer is the correct solution but missing from the top answer is stopping the click event from reaching AgGrid:

```ts
cellRenderer: ({value}) => {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerText = a.href = value;
    a.target = '_blank';
    // Prevent click from reaching AgGrid
    a.addEventListener('click', event => { event.stopPropagation() });
    return a;
}
```

If the click bubbles up to AgGrid it will cause row selection changes, etc if those are enabled.

Comment: Thanks, this solution helped me fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem, and its not straightforward.
We ended up solving it in a different way as we use AdapTable on top of ag-Grid.
So we created an AdapTable Action Column and in the RenderFunction provided the link.  That worked best for us as we didnt always want the Link to appear so we could use the ShouldRender function to decide whether or not we wanted to display link for each row.