# How to add click event on a cell in AgGrid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using AgGrid v28 with Angular 14. I've a very simple requirement. On click of details values I have to call a method.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**My code:**

```
columnDefs = [
    {...},
    {
      headerName: 'Details',
      field: 'partDescription',
      filter: false,
      minWidth: 50,
      cellRendererParams: {
        onClick: this.showPartsHierarchcy.bind(this),
        label: 'partDescription',
        icon: '',
      },
    },
]

showPartsHierarchcy() {
...
}
```

The details column is populated but on click my method `showPartsHierarchcy` is not called. Please correct my mistake.

**I tried:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056668/ag-grid-link-with-link-in-the-cell) answer.

```
cellRenderer: function(params: any) {
  return '<a (click)="showPartsHierarchcy">'+ params.value+'</a>'
}
```

No luck. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I looked more deeply into the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-events/) of Grid Events of AgGrid. This is what I changed in my code:

```
    {
      headerName: 'Details',
      field: 'partDescription',
      filter: false,
      minWidth: 50,
      cellStyle: function (params: any) {
        return { color: '#416AD3' };
      },
      onCellClicked: (event: CellClickedEvent) =>
        console.log('Cell was clicked'),
    },
```

The callback for the cellClicked event is gridOptions.onCellClicked.

```
const gridOptions = {
    // Add event handlers
    onCellClicked: (event: CellClickedEvent) => console.log('Cell was clicked'),
}
```

No `cellRenderer` required. Replace it with `onCellClicked`.