# Ag-grid add column with link

Tags: ag-grid

I use this js-library with rails app. I want add cell that automaticaly generate url for editing row, and when we click it - its redirect for editing page.

**`User`**

```
id---|---name---|---Button
1    | Adam     | /edit/1 link
2    | Nikolay  | /edit/2 link
3    | Peter    | /edit/3 link
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clickable url value in ag-grid with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218532/clickable-url-value-in-ag-grid-with-react)

Answer (score 7):

You could try something like this in your `columnDefs` :

```
  {
    headerName: "Button", field: "id",
    cellRenderer: function(params){
      return "<a href='http://example.com/edit/" 
        + params.value 
        + "'>link "+params.value+"</a>";
    }
  }
```