# Is there a way to 'tag' text within a cell such that that text can be formatted differently and handle click actions?

Tags: formatting, ag-grid

Is there a way to tag areas of text such that the reader knows he/she can click on the text and perform some actions on it such as go to a url.

Ideally the background could be formatted to a 'highlight' color. Once the tag is recognized, 'hover over' and click actions could be implemented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clickable url value in ag-grid with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218532/clickable-url-value-in-ag-grid-with-react)